# Is there something like a wish list for software development?

Tags: list

Is there a service that has a feature like a public wish list for a software?

The idea is that customers can see the work in progress, so they know what is coming next and also up vote features that do not exist at the moment, so we can track what they want/need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fider.io](https://fider.io) is a service we are looking at using.